# How to point to use lz4 for compression

Tags: android, kernel, lz4

Ok, so I need to build TWRP image but I need to point to it to use lz4 instead of gzip format. How to do that I guess it should be in boardconfing.mk under BOARD_MKBOOTIMG_ARGS?